# How to keep the modifications made on the datatable after a search on the datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Currently, I'm working on a datatable. In this datatable, we can modify the data of some columns.
But the problem is that once the user to modify a datum and that makes an interaction with the datatable that is to say "search, numberDisplay, ..." then the displayed data corresponds to the data of the AJAX request.

I'm on 1.11.1 version of "Jquery" and 1.9.4 for "dataTables"

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listeRespPosePlv = $('#listeRespPosePlv').val();
    listeRespPosePlv = JSON.parse(listeRespPosePlv);

    var listeRespPoseFormatted = [];

    $(listeRespPosePlv).each(function(i, v){
        listeRespPoseFormatted.push({'value': v.id_responsable_pose_plv, 'label': v.libelle}); 
    });

    $('#attribution_pose')[0].currentDataTable = $('#attribution_pose').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        'sAjaxSource': Router.url('campagne-plv-attribution'),
        'aLengthMenu': [
            [10, 25, 50, 1000, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, 1000, "All"]
        ],
        'iDisplayLength': 1000,
        'fnServerParams' : function( aoData ) {
            var idCampagnePlv = $('#id_campagne_plv').val();
            aoData.push( { 'name': 'id_campagne_plv', 'value': idCampagnePlv } );
        },
        'fnDrawCallback': function(oSettings){
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();

            var table = this.fnGetData();

            var test = $('#attribution_pose tbody tr');

            for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++){
                    if(table[i][j].localeCompare(test[i].cells[j].children[0].outerHTML) !== 0){
                        console.log('Diff');
                    }else{
                        console.log('Ok');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        'oLanguage': {
            'sUrl': Constante.get('base_full_url')+'assets/vendor/datatables/french.json'    
        }
    }).columnFilter({
        sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
        aoColumns: [
            { type: "text" },  
            { type: "text" },        
            { type: "text" },  
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "select" , values: listeRespPoseFormatted},
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" },
            { type: "text" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { type: "text" }
        ]
    });
});
```

How can I avoid this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to save the user's updates to the location you are retrieving data from before making the search.

Comment: I thank you for your quick response but how can I replace the data that the user has changed ?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you provide some semplified code sample from your attempt